# Trouble getting remote RDP script to work

Tags: powershell, rdp, mstsc

I am writing a script to launch MSTSC from a grid of buttons.  These buttons will each open up a different server connection.  I have a separate button that gets and stores admin creds, that I borrowed from another script.  When clicked, the button calls the `getAdmin` function:

```
function getAdmin {
$returnObject = $null; $credValid = $null;

$cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
$username = $cred.username
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password

$CurrentDomain = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI]"").distinguishedName
$domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($CurrentDomain,$UserName,$Password)

if ($domain.name -eq $null)
{
    $credValid = $false
    $cred = $null
} else {
    $credValid = $true
}
$returnobject = new-object psobject -property @{ Valid = $credValid; Credentials = $cred }
return $returnObject }
```

Then I have my "server buttons:"

```
$btnServ = new-object system.windows.forms.button
$btnServ.location = new-object system.drawing.point (10,200)
$btnServ.text = "Server Name (SERVER)"
$btnServ.width=250
$btnServ.height = 30
$btnServ.add_click({ Start-Process mstsc -ArgumentList "/v:SERVER" -Credential $cred })
```

Now, when I store creds using my first button, then I click the `btnServ` button, it still prompts me for "Windows PowerShell Credential Request" instead of grabbing the stored creds from the previous action. If I remove `-Credential $cred` from the call, whether I click on the first `getAdmin` button or not, it just says that my logon attempt has failed and that I provided the incorrect information.

Ideally, I want to store my creds, then no matter which server button I press it will log me in instead of making my type in my creds twice.

Comment: Where are you calling `getAdmin`? Do you have a line somewhere that populates `$cred`? The function is returning an object with a property Credentials. I would expect something like this in your code. `$cred = (getAdmin).Credentials` inside an if that would check if they were `.Valid` or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably a [scoping issue](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) - the code inside the click event delegate (the `.add_click({})` action) treats the `$cred` variable as local, defaulting to `$null`.

Since you haven't specified a scope for the `$cred` variable inside the `getAdmin` function, they are treated as two separate variables that can't "see" eachother

You can specify the scope like this:

```
$Script:cred
```

So the resulting code becomes:

```
function getAdmin(){
    # code code code
    $Script:cred = Get-Credential
    # more code
}
```

and then:

```
$btnServ.add_click({ Start-Process mstsc -ArgumentList "/v:SERVER" -Credential $Script:cred })
```

Now, both ScriptBlocks refer to the **same** variable in a parent scope, and your `-Credential` switch should work